# Redirect all request to folder /public in azure WebApp with server nginx

Tags: laravel, azure, nginx, cloud

I need to redirect my requirements for the public folder, I can not change the default file located in the/etc/nginx/sites-enaable because the changes are not persistent, such as faco to do this redirection

I tried to configure default but the configuration does not persist.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ***.htaccess*** file in the root of project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```